# Charger for my Mac

Tags: power, home-electronics, power-converter

As discussed in this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250751/power-for-my-us-laptop-in-europe), a [US to Europe Plug Converter Travel Charger Adapter for Apple iBook/MacBook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004VK475Y) could be used. However, this particular entry in Amazon would cost ~14$ and I am located in San Francisco for September. I tried to ship it to Greece, but Amazon wouldn't accept that.

So the questions is if there is this particular hardware piece somewhere in San Francisco, so I can go and pick it. Please recommend!

<sub>Sorry, if this is not the most appropriate question, but I am really desperate on finding one!</sub>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [asking where to buy something is off-topic here](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/543/1).